# 'this' not being set correct using jQuery and CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I am trying to write a rather simple "select all" feature, but I am getting errors with my javascript. The code is rather straight forward, so I'll just post it:

```
(function() {
  $(function() {
    var all_check_box;
    all_check_box = '#tournament_league_127';
    return $(all_check_box).change(function() {
      return $('.leagueCheckBox').each(function() {
        return this.prop("checked", true);
      });
    });
  });
}).call(this);
```

This code was generated by the following CoffeeScript:

```
$ ->
        all_check_box = '#tournament_league_127'
        $(all_check_box).change ->
                $('.leagueCheckBox').each ->
                        this.prop("checked", true)
```

However, when I click #tournament_league_127, I get the following error: `this.prop is not a function`. I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand... what's the difference between `this` and `$(this)`?

Comment: @Erica: `this` is the element the event handler was bound to. `$(this)` calls jQuery with `this` (a DOM element) as argument and returns a jQuery object.

Comment: You can shorten it... `$('.leagueCheckBox').prop("checked", true)`

Comment: @FelixKling: I see, thanks. `this` is used in JavaScript so that the function can easily refer to the object that calls the function even though that nobody knows what that object is, is that right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be  `$(this).prop ...`(assuming jQuery 1.6+, before that `.prop` did not exist).

Comment: @Max: take a look at the comment just posted by am not i am -- *that's* the right answer, since it fixes the problem and removes unnecessary code.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I gave it to you since I couldn't give it to the other guy, and your response is what immediately solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks. The guy didn't add it as an answer anyway... But I recommend you use that.

Answer (score 5):

`this` refers to the element not the jQuery object so you need,

```
return $(this).prop("checked", true);
```